# PDO queries not returning results

Tags: php, pdo

I am unsuccessful when attempting to query a MySQL 5.5.30 server via php5-fpm 5.4.4-14. Here is what we are trying to query:

```
mysql> select * from cat where cat = 'sc';
+------+------+--------------------+
| ID   | cat  | name               |
+------+------+--------------------+
|    1 | sc   | SOLID CARBIDE BITS |
+------+------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here a similar query that first tries getting the category name and then an array which specifies some other fields. The `print_r($result);` and `echo $result['name'];` are not returning results. Is there something I have overlooked when attempting to query the MySQL database using PDO statements?

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database','username','password');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$cat= $_GET["cat"];
/* let try grabbing one of those rows, do not think an array should be here? */
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM cat WHERE cat = :cat');
$stmt->bindParam(':cat', $cat);
/* based on the feedback below, we must execute */
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
echo $result['name'];
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `execute`, try this:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':cat', $cat);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Great, that allows `print_r($result);` to return an array of `Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 2 [cat] => scs [name] => SOLID CARBIDE SPIRAL BITS ) )`, though I am unable to parse a single element from `echo $result['name'];`, is there a better method to return such a query?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL native prepare doesn't support named parameters, so you can change `:cat` to `?`, or set `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` to `true`.

Also, you can add a `try` statement to see the exception and error message.

Answer (score 1):

You can't parse a single element like `$result['name'];` because it is in an subarray.

So you should use something like `$result[0]['name'];` instead to access the subarray.

If you have multiple results, use a foreach loop.
Example:

```
foreach ($result as $subarray) {
    foreach ($subarray as $key => $value) {
         echo "Key: $key \n\n";
         echo "Value: $value \n\n";
    }
}
```

Check out my example:
http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/z7w-jhk